# Bluetooth data shown as 0X80 instead of 0X00

Tags: bluetooth, avr

I have been using Bluetooth module (HC-05) with Atmega8(both A and L) microcontroller to transmit data to my Android device. In following code an 8-bit signed(or unsigned doesn't made any change) value is sent over bluetooth to be displayed on device, this value starts at 0X00 and is incremented in every iteration:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR (F_CPU/16/BAUD-1)

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main (void)
{
uint8_t data = 0;

UBRRH = (MYUBRR >> 8);      // setting higher bits of UBRR
UBRRL = MYUBRR;         // setting lower bit of UBRR

UCSRB = (1 << TXEN);        // transmit enable
UCSRC = ((1 << URSEL) | (1 << UCSZ1) | (1 << UCSZ0));   //URSEL=USART reg selection (R/W), UCSZ1 & UCSZ0 set equal to 011 that is 8 bit data size

while (1)
{
UDR=data;           // loading data in USART Data register (8-bit) and it will be transmitted immidiately
while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));     // waiting till complete data sent and UDRE flag set
_delay_ms(200);         // after some time
data++;             // incrementing data
}
return 0;
}
```

On the android device end there is "Bluetooth spp Pro" app to display the recieved data on screen.

Following is the configuration of recieve mode (Data is displayed as Hex values):

[image: Data is displayed as hex characters and not ASCII]

The data recieved here should  start at 0X00 and go up to 0XFF instead it starts at 0X80 and increments upto 0XFF in a very unfamiliar manner.

[image: continuous stream of data]

Referring above image. The pattern I observed here is that the tens place digit starts at 8 and units place change from 0 to F then in next loop again it becomes 9 and unit place change from 0 to F after that instead of incrementing (expected) tens place again goes to 8 and then in next cycle it again becomes 9, after these four cycles of two repetetive words tens place increments to A and units place change from 0 to F and later the strange tens place pattern reappears for A and B then for C and D and later for E and F at tens place.

So my concern is:

Why is the device showing 80 for 00, as it is correctly working for ones place why is it not working for tens place as expected???

Thanks!!!

**Edit:**

This problem is neither Android version nor device manufacturer specific.

Comment: Do i need some additional hardware?

Comment: Or some error with register values in code.

Comment: The AVR code looks fine to me. Do you have any options regarding char size or parity on the receiver side? Maybe its not matching the 8N1 format from the sender? I would put the `UDR=data` line after the `UDRE` check to make sure its ready to accept data, but that is unlikely the problem.

Comment: Also, it could help to write part of the receive sequence down as binary. That will make it easier to recognize a pattern.

Comment: We don't know exactly how the phone app works, but it may be causing the results you see. It looks like packets of 32 bytes are being sent twice, and that the bytes received have their first bits set to 1 always. Try a different start value to see if the packets have 32 bytes. Change the loop to only send bytes from 0 to 7f to see if the app is modifying the bytes.

Comment: I checked the same code on a different Android app (Bluetooth Module CI) and the results are corresponding to ASCII values (this app shows only ASCII) greater than 0x7F.

Comment: Also it is not Android device specific I tested on two different devices with different versions of Android (kit kat and jelly bean) of different manufacturers (Samsung and Motorola).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with voltage levels. Operating the microcontroller circuit on 3.2V and Bluetooth module on 3.8V solved the problem and data is transmitted as expected. However I am unable to predict an explanation for this.

Please help.

It is observed clearly on varying the potentiometer of voltage regulator, when I keep it below 3.20V data is transmitted smooth, and as the voltage level crosses 3.20V the tens place of data starts getting corrupted up to the point of complete data corruption and output becomes constant data 0XFE at 3.8V.